# Nothing shows up in the terminal after running node js script (twilio)

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am trying to run a simple node js script for making a voice call using Twilio API. The problem is that when I type node app.js, nothing happens and it returns to the console. Like even if there is some kind of error, the error object should be printed into the console, right?

```
const accountSid = PROCESS.ENV.SID;
const authToken = PROCESS.ENV.AUTH;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls
      .create({
         url: 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
         to: PROCESS.ENV.TO,
         from: PROCESS.ENV.FROM
       }), function(err, call){
           if(err){
               console.log(err);
           } else {
               console.log(call.sid)
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

JavaScript is case-sensitive and `PROCESS` does not exist, instead you are looking for `process`. Try replacing all your calls to `PROCESS.ENV` with `process.env` and let me know if that helps.